# Error Context while loading an array after a query is sent

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, service, angular7

I have two angular components ( they are not parent/child components)
I'm trying to load the second component after a search button is clicked in the first component.
when the button search is clicked I will verify if there is some filter inputs to make the search based on them , if yes I will send a request with only the filter params if not I will send a request and show all the array as it is.

Here is what I did

the first component containing the filter inputs

```
export class FilterBarComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  filterParam: any = filterDataObject;
  buttonStatus: boolean;
  @Output() eventClicked: EventEmitter<boolean> = new 
EventEmitter<boolean>();


  constructor(private sharedService: SharedDataService) {
    this.buttonStatus = false;
  }
  ngOnInit() {

  }
  onClick(event: boolean): void {
    this.buttonStatus = true; // this.buttonStatus = !event :to toggle the 
     status of the button between true and false
    this.eventClicked.emit(this.buttonStatus);
    this.sharedService.updateTableView(this.buttonStatus);
    this.removeEmptyValueFromFilterParam(this.filterParam);
    this.sharedService.updatedDataSelection
    (this.removeEmptyValueFromFilterParam(this.filterParam));
   }

  // To remove the empty params from the request
  removeEmptyValueFromFilterParam(obj: any) {
   this.filterParam = {};
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((prop) => {
      if (obj[prop] !== '') { this.filterParam[prop] = obj[prop]; }
    });
      return this.filterParam;
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
       this.buttonStatus = !this.buttonStatus;

  }

}
```

the second component:

```
export class LogsTableComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, 
OnDestroy {
  @Input() clicked: boolean;
  private subscription: Subscription;
  filtredLogs: Ilogs[];
  filterParamCriteria: any;
  subscribed: boolean = false;
  constructor(private logsService: HttpClientTestService, private 
  sharedService: SharedDataService) {
  }


   ngOnInit() {
     this.getLogs();
   }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
  }

  getLogs() {
    if (this.isEmpty(this.filterParamCriteria) > 0) {
     this.getLogsWithQueryFilter();
    } else {
    this.getLogsWithoutParam();
   }

  }

  getLogsWithoutParam() {
  this.filtredLogs = [];
  this.logsService.getLogsWithoutParam().subscribe((res) => {
  this.filtredLogs = res;
  console.log(res);
  },
    err => {
    return console.error(err);
   }  
  );

}

 getLogsWithQueryFilter() {
   this.filtredLogs = [];

 this.logsService.getLogsWithQueryParam
 (this.filterParamCriteria).subscribe((res) => {
  this.filtredLogs = res;
  console.log(res);
   },
  err => {
    return console.error(err);
  }
 );

 }

getFilterParamCriteria() {
this.subscription = this.sharedService.data$.subscribe(filterParam => {
  if (filterParam) {
    console.log('get filter param');
    this.filterParamCriteria = filterParam;
    if (this.isEmpty(this.filterParamCriteria) > 0) {
      console.log(this.isEmpty(this.filterParamCriteria));
      this.subscribed = true;
      console.log(this.subscribed);
      console.log(this.filterParamCriteria);
    }

  } else {
    this.filterParamCriteria = {};
    this.subscribed = false;
  }
  return this.filterParamCriteria;
});
}

 isEmpty(obj) {
   return Object.keys(obj).length;
  }


getShowTableView() {
  this.subscription = 
  this.sharedService.data$_showTable.subscribe(showTable =>
  {
  if (showTable) {
    console.log('get show table ');
    this.clicked = showTable;
    console.log(this.clicked);
  } else {
    this.clicked = !showTable;

  }
 });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
   this.subscription.unsubscribe();

}
}
```

sharedService is to share data between the two components

```
 const FILITER_DATA = {};
 const SHOWTABL_FLAG = false;
 @Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
 })
 export class SharedDataService {

  private filterStore = new BehaviorSubject(FILITER_DATA);

  private showTable = new BehaviorSubject(SHOWTABL_FLAG);;

  data$: Observable<any> = this.filterStore.asObservable();

  data$_showTable: Observable<any> = this.showTable.asObservable();
  constructor() { }

  updatedDataSelection(data: any) {
    this.filterStore.next(data);
  }

  updateTableView(data: any) {
     this.showTable.next(data);
  }
}
```

when I try to run it I got a context error :

```
ERROR TypeError: "can't convert undefined to object"
   isEmpty logs-table.component.ts:85
   getLogs logs-table.component.ts:30
   ngOnInit logs-table.component.ts:23
```

Can you help me to know why this error occurs and if you have any suggestion to do the work in other way even if I will change all the structure please tell me .

Comment: it seems like you don't call getFilterParamCriteria function anywhere?

Comment: it's just to verify if there are parameters or not and use them while calling the  getLogsWithQueryFilte(). I know there are errors somewhere but I can't figure it out .

Comment: You are calling getLogs in ngOnInit but filterParamCriteria is undefined. I don't know what is that for but you need to initialize that object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create filterParamCriteria variable, you can try set first value as empty object.

For example:

```
filterParamCriteria: any = {};
```

method  `isEmpty()` return errors when obj is null or undefined

Comment: yes it solved the problem but still neither is empty () or getLogsWithQueryFilte() are runned :(

Comment: You can try run getFilterParamCriteria() method in ngOnInit()?